# How can I click on a RecyclerView item to go to detailed activity and apply the title and price of the item in the RecyclerView that I clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have `Recyclerview` items in `MainActivity`.

When I click `recyclerview` item in `mainactivity`, go to `detailactivity`.
And then I want apply the `titleText` and price of the item(realValueText) in the `recyclerview` that i clicked in `detailactivity`. How can I do ? Lets see `acitivity` and `adapter`.

and u can see `detailactivity`. finally I want make details view,

```
productTitle==titleText , productPoint==realValueText.
```

**MainFragment**

```
class MainFragment: Fragment(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    var itemList: MutableList<ItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? { return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false)}

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        itemList.clear()

        swipeRefreshLo.setOnRefreshListener(this)

        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item1", 49000, 29000, "r_300_x_300_3"))
        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item2", 49000, 29000, "main_cup"))
        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item3", 49000, 29000, "main_perfume"))
        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item4", 49000, 29000, "main_fan"))
        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item5", 49000, 29000, "main_bear"))
        itemList.add(ItemDataVo("item6", 49000, 29000, "main_glass"))

        val itemRecyclerAdapter= ItemRecyclerAdapter(context!!,itemList)
        recycler_view.adapter=itemRecyclerAdapter
        recycler_view.layoutManager = androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(context)


    }


    override fun onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLo.isRefreshing = false

        }

    }
```

**ItemDataVo**

```
class ItemDataVo(title: String, realValue: Int, pointValue: Int, imageView: String, viewType: Int = 0) {
    var viewType = viewType
    var title :String = title
    var realValue:Int = realValue
    var pointValue:Int =pointValue
    var image :String = imageView
}
```

**ItemRecyclerAdapter**

```
 class ItemRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, private var dataList: MutableList<ItemDataVo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerAdapter.Holder>() {


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
          val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_1_col_list, parent, false)
          return Holder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
          holder?.bind(dataList[position],context)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size
        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = dataList[position].viewType


        inner class Holder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {
            var titleText = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.titleText) as TextView
            var realValueText = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.realValueText) as TextView
            var pointValueText = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.pointValueText) as TextView
            var imageView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.imageView)as ImageView
            var itemLayout = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.item_layout) as ConstraintLayout

            fun bind(data:ItemDataVo, context: Context) {
                if(data.image !="") {
                    val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(data.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
                    imageView?.setImageResource(resourceId)
                }else {
                    imageView?.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                }

                pointValueText?.text=data.pointValue.toString() + "P"
                realValueText?.text=data.realValue.toString()
                titleText?.text=data.title
                itemLayout?.setOnClickListener {
                    val i = Intent(it.context, DetailItemViewActivity::class.java)
                    it.context.startActivity(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**DetailItemViewActivity**

```
class DetailItemViewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


    var Detailslist: MutableList<DetailItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        var productTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.productTitle)
        var productpoint = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.productPoint)
```

Comment: follow this link.  https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Interface like this

```
    public interface ClickInterface {

    public void recyclerviewOnClick(int position);
}
```

Implement it in your Fragment and initialize the interface

```
  YourFragment extends Fragment implements ClickInterface{

private ClickInterface listner;

------- Your oncreateView   --------
listner=this; //Now pass this in your adapter
    }
```

In your adapter constructor get this listner like this

```
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset,ClickInterface listner){
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
    this.listner=listner;
}
```

and at last in your ViewHolder

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);


itemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    listner.recyclerviewOnClick(getAdapterPosition());

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now you will get the position in your fragment in

```
   public void recyclerviewOnClick(int position){
// Here you will get the position
}
```

Comment: Thank u r comment. please, Can u explain more detail use kotlin?.

Comment: @DaesikPark what details you want from my side if you want the same code in kotlin you can convert it to kotlin via android studio

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to let your activity or fragment which holds the recycler view to open the details screen.

Set a`onClick` listener in the viewholder or in any individual view if the recycler item. When that view is clicked, send a callback to your parent activity. Send the model which was clicked inside the listener callback.

Your activity will get this callback and open the relevant activity.

This way your recycler adapter wont have the reference of the details screen.